# Folder Picker not loading outside ISE

Tags: powershell

I have a script that starts with a folder picker dialog, however I understand that POSH can't execute scripts outside of ISE like that (STA vs. MTA), so I have a separate script to dot-source it.

I have error handling in the first script in case the user presses Cancel:

```
if ($Show -eq "OK") {
    return $objForm.SelectedPath
} else {
    Write-Error "Operation cancelled by user."
    exit
}
```

Now I need for the 2nd script (the one calling the first script) to detect the same Cancellation.

This is what I've got so far:

```
"Choose a folder containing the items to be moved..."
""
try {
    powershell -STA -File "C:\Test\Script.ps1"
    ""
    "Operation completed. An event log has been created:"
    (Resolve-Path .\).Path +"\log.txt"
    ""
    "Press any key to continue..."
    ""
    $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
} catch {
    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) { exit $LastExitCode }
    Write-Host "User cancelled the operation."
    ""
    "Press any key to continue..."
    ""
    $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
```

That gives me a nasty looking multi-line Write Error Exception in red text.

```
At C:\Test\Script.ps1:27 char:30
+ $folder = Select-FolderDialog <<<<  #contains user's selected folder
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Select-FolderDialog
```

I'm not sure why it's generating an error message referencing the other script, since the other script runs fine (from ISE of course).

**Desired Output:**

If user cancels folder picker, I just want a nice clean error message to display:

> User cancelled the operation.
>   Press any key to continue.

**Edit**

Here is the folder picker script I have. It works fine in ISE but when you Right Click and choose Run with Powershell it just launches a blank prompt window. To prevent the end user from accidentally editing the script I would like for it to run from outside ISE. BTW, I am using POSH 2.

```
 # Function for folder picker dialog
Function Select-FolderDialog
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null     

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
# Default location is script's location
$objForm.SelectedPath = (Resolve-Path .\).Path
$objForm.Description = "Select Folder"
$Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
If ($Show -eq "OK")
{Return $objForm.SelectedPath}
    Else
    {
    Write-Error "Operation cancelled by user."
    Exit
    }
}
$folder = Select-FolderDialog #contains user's selected folder
```

Comment: So you're calling script one (the shot one) and that's supposed to call script two? Whats the point in slitting into separate files?

Comment: I agree with restless1987, and don't understand why you are splitting the folder selection out into it's own script. Personally I just have a function that I drop into scripts that need it to perform the folder select dialog, but it could just as easily be its own .ps1 file that I dot source to load the function. I am also curious why your are calling PowerShell like that and forcing STA to load the script.

Comment: I can't find the page now, but I saw a forum regarding the issue I was having. All was fine until I realized the original script wouldn't run at all from explorer, only from within ISE. And someone mentioned it was an issue with STA vs MTA (no clue) and then recommended creating a 2nd script to dot-source it. That worked. Except I quickly realized it didn't have error handling. I would love to have just one script. But how do I get it to work from outside ISE?

Comment: I updated my original post. Please see where it says "Edit."

Answer (score 0):

Keep just your function in your 2nd script, dot source the file to load the function, then place the `$folder = Select-FolderDialog` call in your main script, a la:

```
"Choose a folder containing the items to be moved..."
""
try {
    . "C:\Test\Script.ps1" # this dot sources the function from the second file (no need to call a separate Powershell process to do this, as data from that process won't be returned to the primary process calling it)

    $folder = Select-FolderDialog # this runs the function in your original script, storing the result in the $folder variable

    ""
    "Operation completed. An event log has been created:"
    (Resolve-Path .\).Path +"\log.txt"
    ""
    "Press any key to continue..."
    ""
    $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
} catch {
    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) { exit $LastExitCode }
    Write-Host "User cancelled the operation."
    ""
    "Press any key to continue..."
    ""
    $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
```

Comment: It seems that this method of calling the script doesn't work properly (at least for my version). it just launches a powershell.exe window with the opening message but not the folder picker. I have tried it several times.

Comment: It kinda looks like try/catch is the fail point. I noticed that the catch host message never appears. Even if the function is cancelled it never says "user cancelled the operation." So I removed it just to see what would happen and I just left the dot-source and host messages and it operates exactly the same as it did with the try/catch.